# Use exact value from a list to search another list. Append variable with results from search

Tags: python, loops, search

I need to create a list/dataframe that has component ID's along with their description. I have a list containing the component ID and another list containing the component ID with a description. Only components with an ID in both lists should be displayed along with its description.

I have tried to use the component ID list to exact search in the component and description list. I wasn't able to get a desired output.

```
desclist = ['R402 MSG ='4k2 1%'','R403 MSG ='100 1%'','R404 MSG ='4k 1%'']

component = ['R402','R403','R404']

combinedlist = []

while count<(len(component) - 1):
    while True:
        for c in desclist:
            if c in component[count]:
                combinedlist.append(c)
                print(comp[count]+ ' , ' +  desclist[count])
                count = count + 1
```

This is not code I've tried but believe is similar to what I need, I'm aware there is no loop until in python.

I expect the output to be something like:

```
R402 , MSG ='4k2 1%'
```

This will require me to remove everything before the equals in the description list.

Comment: `desclist` has an issue with quotes, you could fix it

Comment: Your expected output should have all values as their ID's are present in `component`, right?

Comment: But R403 and R404 are also in both lists. Why aren't them in the expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple (easy to understand) way to accomplish what you need!

```
desclist = ['R402 MSG = Desc402','R403 MSG = Desc403',
            'R404 MSG = Desc404','R405 MSG = Desc405']
component = ['R402','R403','R404','R406']
combinedlist = []
for i in range(len(component)):
    found = False
    for j in range(len(desclist)):
        if str(component[i]) == str(desclist[j]).split(' ')[0]:
            found = True
            combinedlist.append(component[i] + ', ' + desclist[j].split(' ',1)[1])
            print(component[i], ',', desclist[j].split(' ',1)[1])
            #print('Comp : ', component[i], 'Desc : ', desclist[j].split(' ',1)[1])
            break
    if not found:
        print(component[i], ' not found in Description List')
print('Combined List : ', combinedlist)
```

**Output:**

```
R402 , MSG = Desc402
R403 , MSG = Desc403
R404 , MSG = Desc404
R406  not found in Description List
Combined List :  ['R402, MSG = Desc402', 'R403, MSG = Desc403', 'R404, MSG = Desc404']
```

I have changed your description & component lists to cover all scenarios you may face. Also, your description list has extra quotes in each element. You would have to use [escape characters](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) if you want to keep these quotes in your list.

In your combined list, if you want to remove everything before the equal to sign (in description list) then use any one of the below (depending on all the elements in your description list).

```
desclist[j].split('=',1)[1]
desclist[j].rpartition('=')[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>> desclist = ['R402 MSG = "4k2 1%"','R403 MSG ="100 1%"','R404 MSG ="4k 1%"', 'R407 MSG ="4k 1%"']

# For test i have added 'R407 MSG ="4k 1%"'

>>> component = ['R402','R403','R404']
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> new_list = [[desc for desc in desclist if cid in desc] for cid in component]    
>>> list(chain(*new_list))

['R402 MSG = "4k2 1%"', 'R403 MSG ="100 1%"', 'R404 MSG ="4k 1%"']
```

Comment: Hi, I got an error in the program "list index out of range". The component ID list has ~1300 values and the description one has ~2500. Some descriptions don't have a component ID or are even just blank, I'm not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: @mark7378 I have used `chain` to flatten the list. So, it should not create list of list.